# AWS S3 GetObject Erroring Sometimes for Batch

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, next.js

Currently experiencing an error within my Next.js setup where I am getting transient errors when requesting objects from S3 within a `for` loop. Esentially, when I request single files there is no error, but when I request from a loop it breaks, **but only sometimes.** Seems to be a type of "warm up" error, if I retry the batch request multiple times it will eventually work (but I do not need to do this for my single file requests).

**Exact Error:**

```
VM1409:1 GET https://{link-to-bucket}{key.jpg}?response-content-disposition=attachment&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg 403 (Forbidden)
```

which is also shown with

```
Uncaught (in promise) SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

**Steps I've Tried to Fix:**

- Made sure my access key id and secret are correct (this doesn't change when I'm requesting one  file or when I am requesting multiple as below)
- Specified the response content type and response content disposition
- Tried with and without specifying `signatureVersion: "v4"`

**Code:**

```js
// getObjectS3 performs a request to the specified s3 bucket with
// the specified params and retries 3 times on failure.
function getObjectS3(params, bucketRegion, errorPrefix) {
    /*
        Inputs:
            - params (object): Params object
            - bucketRegion (string): Specified bucket name
            - errorPrefix (string): Prefix string to be shown on failure
    */
    aws.config.update(
        {
            "accessKeyId": process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID,
            "secretAccessKey": process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            "region": bucketRegion,
        }
    )
    let S3 = new aws.S3({
        signatureVersion: "v4"
    })



    let objectGetter = S3.getObject(params, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return S3.getObject(params, (err2) => {
                if (err) {
                    return S3.getObject(params, (err3) => {
                        if (err2) {
                            console.log(errorPrefix, err3)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
    return objectGetter.promise()
}


let imageFilenames = [
  "key1.jpg",
  "key2.jpg",
  ...
  "key8.jpg"
]

let bucketRegion = "..."
let bucketName = "..."
let errorPrefix = "there is something wrong. hmm...."

let imageBatchData = []
for (let i = 0; i < imageFilenames.length; i++) {
    let imageDataGetter = getObjectS3({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imageFilenames[i],
        ResponseContentType: "image/jpeg",
        ResponseContentDisposition: "attachment"
    }, bucketRegion, errorPrefix)
    imageBatchData.push(imageDataGetter)
}
```

This code is run when the Page component is mounted. Also worth noting there are never more than  10 - 11 keys in the list that I am requesting.

Comment: Does some of the object keys contain special character?

Comment: @jellycsc The object keys have forward slashes. So something like "this/is/the/key.jpg". Does that change the way the signature is calculated?